# Integral involving Bessel function

Tags: integration, bessel-functions

$\int_0^\infty dx \frac{xJ_0(ax)}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$, where $J_0$ is the zeroth-order Bessel function.

Comment: You can probably derive it using Cauchy's theorem and going to the complex plane. In any case Mathematica gives the result as e^{-a}/a for a>0. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called the Hankel transform and corresponds to the Fourier en transform in dimension $2$ of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+|x|^2}}$ (see [Fourier transform of a radial function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1310936/fourier-transform-of-a-radial-function) or [Equation (23)](https://www.math.arizona.edu/%7Efaris/methodsweb/hankel.pdf)). As written [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_transform#Some_Hankel_transform_pairs), it is $$\frac{e^{-a}}{a}$$